# How can I use 2 textbox in WHERE?

Tags: vb.net

How can I use 2 textbox(txtFrom and txtTo) in WHERE OrderDate? Sorry I'm new and I just don't know what to put here. Thanks

```
 Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT CustomerName, ProductName, Quantity, Amount, OrderDate FROM Orders WHERE Orderdate", con)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT CustomerName, ProductName, Quantity, Amount, OrderDate FROM Orders WHERE Orderdate Between '" + txtFrom.Text + "' AND '" + txtTo.Text + "'", con)
```

but this is not Recommended. Try to use **Parametrized query** like this

```
String sSQL = "SELECT CustomerName, ProductName, Quantity, Amount, OrderDate FROM Orders WHERE Orderdate Between @Start And @End";        
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("ConnectionString");    
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();         
cmd.Connection = conn;    
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;    
cmd.CommandText = sb.ToString();         
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Start ", txtFrom.Text);    
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@End", txtTo.Text);
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of SQL injection; you should use a parameterized query to avoid this.

Comment: Oh,sory but it only shows the value in 2 textboxes not value from one to another